# Freshly installed Xcode 5.1 cannot install all components then crashes on start

Tags: crash, installation, xcode5, crash-reports

I just downloaded and installed Xcode 5.1. On first start it tells me that other things have to be installed. After a while the install progress bar stops showing progress and the system tells me, that Xcode doesn't react anymore. After waiting for half an hour, then force quitting and trying to restart Xcode the program crashes immediately. I deleted Xcode and tried all procedures again with the same result.

UPDATE: Also Google Chrome shows the same behavior now.

Here is my crash report (shortened):

```
Process:         Xcode [53594]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         5.1 (5084)
Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-5084000000000000~21
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 444172641
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [265]
Responsible:     Xcode [53594]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-03-14 11:33:06.553 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.2 (13C64)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  FE8DD7AF-812E-864D-CE27-947396E2F660

Sleep/Wake UUID: CC7CABDC-AD7F-4EE5-BF67-D47A77A43237

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_GUARD
Exception Codes: 0x4000000200000000, 0x00007fff8730dc48

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5B130a

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff870c913a dup + 10
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8c0f9cee -[NSConcreteTask launchWithDictionary:] + 2457
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8c0f8d58 +[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:arguments:] + 200
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff853df959 NSUpdateDynamicServices + 291
4   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000108d6bfc3 +[IDEInstrumentsLaunchHelper setupInstrumentsLoginItemsIfNecessary] + 255
5   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000108d6ace8 -[IDEWelcomeWindowController _showFirstLaunchExperienceIfAppropriate] + 240
6   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000108d6abdb -[IDEWelcomeWindowController openWelcomeWindowAfterFirstLaunchExperienceIfAppropriate:] + 29
7   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x0000000108d6ab07 -[IDEApplicationController applicationOpenUntitledFile:] + 230
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84eb1e20 -[NSApplication _doOpenUntitled] + 447
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84dd4f01 __58-[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:]_block_invoke + 254
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84dd4c23 __78-[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke_2 + 140
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84dd480d -[NSDocumentController(NSInternal) _autoreopenDocumentsWithCompletionHandler:] + 746
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84c3fb7b -[NSApplication _reopenWindowsAsNecessaryIncludingRestorableState:registeringAsReady:completionHandler:] + 323
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84c3f909 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:] + 557
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84c3f36b -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 242
15  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8bf8af0a -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 294
16  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8bf8ad7d _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 106
17  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8d751e1f aeDispatchAppleEvent(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*, unsigned int, unsigned char*) + 381
18  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8d751c32 dispatchEventAndSendReply(AEDesc const*, AEDesc*) + 31
19  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff8d751b36 aeProcessAppleEvent + 315
20  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8d282161 AEProcessAppleEvent + 56
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84c3b246 _DPSNextEvent + 1026
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84c3aa2b -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
23  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010832de31 -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 84
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84c2eb2c -[NSApplication run] + 553
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84c19913 NSApplicationMain + 940
26  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff82fac5fd start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff870c8e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f455f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f458fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff870c9662 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff872fb43d _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 239
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff872fb152 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff870c8e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f455f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f458fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff870c8e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f455f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f458fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff870c8e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f455f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f458fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff870c4a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff870c3d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff86a5e155 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff86a5d779 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff86a5d0b5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8bfd0967 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 348
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8bfd076b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f454899 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f45472a _pthread_start + 137
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f458fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:: com.apple.appkit-heartbeat
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff870c8a3a __semwait_signal + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86363dc0 nanosleep + 200
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86363cb2 usleep + 54
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff84e9f21d -[NSUIHeartBeat _heartBeatThread:] + 2132
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8bfd076b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f454899 _pthread_body + 138
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f45472a _pthread_start + 137
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f458fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff870c89aa __select + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff86aa9b83 __CFSocketManager + 867
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f454899 _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f45472a _pthread_start + 137
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f458fc9 thread_start + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff870c8e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f455f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f458fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff870c8e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f455f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f458fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff870c8e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f455f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f458fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff870c8e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f455f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f458fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff870c8e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f455f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f458fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff870c8e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f455f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f458fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff870c8e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f455f08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8f458fb9 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000001  rbx: 0x00007fff57fcbae8  rcx: 0x00007fff57fcb918  rdx: 0x00000000ee09ff00
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000003  rbp: 0x00007fff57fcbc20  rsp: 0x00007fff57fcb918
   r8: 0x0000000000000003   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000246
  r12: 0x00007fcbc1edbf40  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x00007fff73f8f458  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff870c913a  rfl: 0x0000000000000247  cr2: 0x0000000108d6b92a

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000029
Trap Number:     133
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able solve the problem by repairing rights with disk utility and reboot the system. Both Xcode and Chrome start without crashing now.

Comment: Can you provide more details? E.g. exact steps that you took and the report that the disk utility gave you?